# How to deploy a GAE app on CentOS server using appscale?

Tags: google-app-engine, web-applications, centos7

I have a developed application on Google App Engine, my customers wants to deploy it on a private virtual machine, that are running CentOS 7. I have read about appscale but this is only for ubuntu and can be installed on CentOS.

Could anyone help?

Thanks

Comment: https://appscalesystems.zendesk.com/hc/communities/public/questions/200282909-Do-you-have-plans-to-support-AppScale-on-CentOS- says CentOS support "It's in our backlog" (Appscale's) but "using AppScale within images or containers, which limits the immediacy of the need to port AppScale directly to different distros".  So you can try using AppScale in a docker container, per http://www.appscale.com/2013/10/30/appscale-on-docker/ and https://github.com/AppScale/appscale/wiki/Docker or virtualbox per https://github.com/AppScale/appscale/wiki/AppScale-on-VirtualBox .

Comment: Thanks! I would try!